# Fault localisation using model checking

Tags: algorithms, graphs, model-checking, software-testing

In many papers like [Empirical Evaluation of the Tarantula Automatic Fault-Localization Technique](http://spideruci.org/papers/jones05.pdf) there is a good explanation about how tarantula algorithm can be used with test suits. Is there any book or even explanation of how this could be usefull in case of model checking? with abstract reachability graph?

Comment: This seems vague, can you describe what the tarantula algorithm is briefly and define some context? Specifically you could say what you mean by the test suites and abstract reachability graph, and what is the input to the model checking you have in mind.

Comment: can i please content with you ?